# JFrame en Blanco, no me muestra el contenido

Tags: java, jframe

Estoy teniendo un inconveniente con los JFrame de Java. Sucede que tengo un `JFrame1` que recibe una entrada y luego crea un `JFrame2` en donde le setea uno atributo, lo pone visible y luego llama a un metodo de ese `JFrame2`.

Sucede que cuando el `JFrame2` se habre me aparece en blanco, como que se congela y no muestra nada hasta que termine de procesar los datos. Mi idea era que el `JFrame2` sea una pantalla de "Espere".

[image: Aqui dejo una imagen sobre lo que me refiero]

Este es el codigo de cuando llamo al JFrame2 (this seria el JFrame1 y BarraProgreso el JFrame2):

```
  BarraProgreso barra= new BarraProgreso ();

           barra.setRutaFinal(this.getRutaFinal());
           barra.setMinConf(MinConf);
           barra.setMinSup(MinSup); 
           barra.setVisible(true);
           barra.GeneracionItemsCandidatos();
           this.dispose();
```

Comment: Vas a tener muchos problemas si utilizas más de un JFrame. Ese nuevo jFrame que quieres desplegar sustituyelo por un JDialog. Si quieres hacer una espera con el JFrame no vas a poder bloquear el otro JFrame. Te dará muchos problemas.

Comment: Creo que lo que necesitas es más bien un nuevo hilo. Lo que describes es causa de que alguna operación se realiza antes de `barra.setVisible(true)` se ejecuta e impide que aparezca tu info a mostrar.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo sería un barra multi hilo para que despues de que se visualice la barra siga trabajando mientras los datos se modifican. Tendras que hacer algunas adaptaciones.

```
class BarraDeProgreso extends JDialog{

    private Thread hilo;
    private JProgressBar barra;
    private int totalDeLaBarra = 2000;
    private int velocidad = 1;

    BarraDeProgreso() {
        this.hilo = new Thread(this::contador);
        barra = new JProgressBar(0,totalDeLaBarra);
        barra.setValue(0);
        this.add(barra);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
        this.setModal(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean b) {
        hilo.start();
        super.setVisible(b);

    }



    public void contador(){
        int contador = 0;
        while (contador<=totalDeLaBarra+1) {            
            try {
                barra.setValue(contador);
                hilo.sleep(velocidad);
                contador++;

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(BarraDeProgreso.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se va a cerrar la barra!");
        dispose();

    }



}



public class NewClass {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
        frame1.setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton boton = new JButton("Frame2");
        frame1.add(boton);


        boton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                BarraDeProgreso barra = new BarraDeProgreso();
                barra.setVisible(true);

            }

        });

        frame1.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

Comment: una barra de progreso que mide el avance del tiempo....